# Gradient of draws from random variables

Tags: derivatives, random-variables

In the context of neural networks there has recently been some interest in differentiation incarnations of random variables.

**Example.** Given a random variable $y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Now let $\hat{y}$ be a sample from $y$, how can we calculate ${\partial \hat{y} / \partial \mu}$ and ${\partial \hat{y} / \partial \sigma}$?

One way to do this is to use a helper distribution $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ and reparametrize $y' = \mu + \sigma \epsilon$. We can then use the simple rules of calculus to find ${\partial \hat{y} / \partial \mu}$ and ${\partial \hat{y} / \partial \sigma}$ because all stochasticity is now within $\epsilon$.

This can also be done with many more distributions.

Does anyone know how this trick is called or who used it first? Or was it unknown just until recently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ease the exposition, let us stick to families $\{P_\theta\,;\,\theta\in\Theta\}$ indexed by a single parameter $\theta$.

To compute $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\theta}\hat y$ at a given $\theta$, it seems one should be able to build a sample $(y^t_k)$ of distribution $P_t$ from a sample $(y^\theta_k)$ of distribution $P_{\theta}$, at least for every $t$ in a neighborhood of $\theta$.

The gaussian case $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with $\theta=\mu$ fits in this framework thanks to the identity $$y^m_k=y^\mu_k+m-\mu$$ for every $m$, which yields $$\hat y^m=\hat y^\mu+m-\mu,$$ and finally $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\mu}\hat y=1,$$ for every $\mu$.
Likewise, for $\theta=\sigma$, one can make use of the realizations $$y^\sigma_k=\mu+\sigma\epsilon_k$$ for every $\sigma$, with $\epsilon_k$ i.i.d. standard normal. This yields $$y^s_k=\mu+s\sigma^{-1}(y^\sigma_k-\mu)$$ for every $s$, hence $$\hat y^s=\mu+s\sigma^{-1}(\hat y^\sigma-\mu)$$ and finally, $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\sigma}\hat y=\sigma^{-1}(\hat y-\mu).$$
Each time, the crucial tool seems to be the simultaneous realization on some common probability space of a sample $(y^\theta_k)$ for every value of the parameter $\theta$, using the same random input.

> What comes to mind in this context is the notion of *coupling* of random variables or stochastic processes.

To be more specific, if such a coupling yields that, for every $\theta$,
$$
\hat y=G(\theta,\epsilon),
$$
where $\epsilon$ is some random variable or some stochastic process which does not depend on $\theta$, then
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\theta}\hat y=\frac{\partial G}{\partial\theta}(\theta,\epsilon).
$$

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration. Yet, my question was aiming more at whether this procedure is well known and if, under which name or who to credit for it. But I will look into coupling further.